# how to call getString() from inside pagerAdapter

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public SliderAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String[] slide_headings = {
            context.getString(R.string.onboard1Header),
            context.getString(R.string.onboard2Header),
            context.getString(R.string.onboard3Header)
    };
}
```

I have tried to pass in context and also tried getResources().getString(), still did not work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: DOnt use AndroidStudio tag if you dont have question related to IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
public String[] slide_headings = {
        context.getString(R.string.onboard1Header),
        context.getString(R.string.onboard2Header),
        context.getString(R.string.onboard3Header)
};
```

To

```
private int[] slide_headings = {
        R.string.onboard1Header,
        R.string.onboard2Header,
        R.string.onboard3Header
};
```

And use it like this:

```
String yourString = context.getResources().getString(slide_headings[yout_index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your string with `getResources()` method :

```
String yourString = context.getResources().getString(R.string.yourResource);
```